# How to change Javadoc index.html link to another link?

Tags: maven, javadoc

I just wonder if it is possible to change a link to Javadoc generated by maven site? 
I mean, if you generate javadoc then you have a ../index.html address and if it is possible to change index.html to smth else? I generate a classic javadoc and doclet rtf, and both generate index.html, for the classic javadoc I leave as it is, but for doclet I'd like to have a link to rtf not to index.html...I hope you understand what do i mean. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the maven-javadoc-plugin twice times with [differernt configurations for the outputDirectory and for the reportOutputDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html). After that you need to create a new start location page to get the information into your generated site. You can simply try to create link in the site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic solution; you will have to write your own shell script.

Put the code to generate the site into a shell script and then rename the `index.html` file afterwards.

If you don't like shell scripts, use a small Ant build file which invokes Maven. You could try the reverse (and Ant task in your Maven POM) but then, you'd have to add that in the right spot in the life cycle which isn't always easy. I find the simple solution (Ant calls Maven) more "obvious".